# Who consecrated Scipione Rebiba?

Tags: catholicism, medieval-church, apostolic-succession, scipione-rebiba

[His Eminence Scipione Rebiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scipione_Rebiba) is considered as the last bishop most Roman Catholic bishops can trace their episcopal lineages from. Who consecrated Scipione Rebiba? If we don't know, are there at least theories on who did?

The [*Wikipedia* article on him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scipione_Rebiba#Episcopal_succession) says:

> "However, since it is canon law that there must be at least three bishops present at a consecration, it is possible to bypass Rebiba using the bishops who cooperated with him in his consecrations."

Are there any records about who cooperated with him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Who consacrated Scipione Rebiba?**

As there exists no documented evidence on this subject matter, it is widely believed that Bishop Rebiba was consecrated by **Cardinal Gian Pietro Carafa**, archbishop of Chieti.

He was consecrated a bishop on 14 May 1541 at the age of 37.

> It is widely believed that Bishop Rebiba was consecrated by Cardinal Gian Pietro Carafa, archbishop of Chieti, who became [Pope Paul IV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Paul_IV). However, no documentary evidence has been found to verify this hypothesis (Charles N. Branson Jr., Apostolic Succession in the Roman Catholic Church). - [The Cardinals of the Holy Roman Church](https://cardinals.fiu.edu/bios1555-ii.htm#Rebiba)

Most recent episcopal "lineages" begin with Rebiba himself including Pope Benedict XVI.

> While it is generally accepted that Rebiba was consecrated by Giovanni Pietro Caraffa, founder of the Theatines and later Pope Paul IV, most recent episcopal "lineages" begin with Rebiba himself, who was a contemporary of Emperor Charles V.
>
> Rebiba eventually ended up working in the Roman curia, receiving appointment to the commission of the Holy Office (Inquisition) for the Naples district in 1553, but he assumed similar duties in Rome in 1555, the same year he became a Cardinal.
>
> The following year, he travelled to Brussels and France on a diplomatic mission, returning to Italy to accept the See of Pisa, which he administered through a vicar. In 1559 he participated in the conclave which elected his mentor, Caraffa, as Paul IV. By now he was a Vatican bureaucrat in every sense - which is how he is depicted in the painting shown here. He participated in the next conclave, in 1565, which elected Pius V, and that of 1572, which elected Gregory XIII. He eventually became Major Inquisitor. - [Scipione Rebiba](http://www.bestofsicily.com/mag/art385.htm)